# Algorithm for generating a non-overlapping rectangles

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I'm working on a problem where I need to generate a rectangle (let's call it 'box') within a larger rectangle ('field'), ensuring that the box doesn't overlap with a smaller rectangle ('window') contained within the field. For simplicity, *all the coordinates are integers greater or equal to 0*.

Here's the specific problem:

- I have the coordinates of the lower left corner (LL) and upper right
  corner (UR) of both the field (light blue) and the window (white).
- The randomly generated box (dark blue) needs to be completely within the field but should have *no common points* and *no overlaps* with the window.

[image]

I've managed to solve the problem in the 2D case. However, my solution involved tedious consideration of all possible relations between the random coordinates of the box with respect to the field and the window.

Now, I'm looking for a more generalized and robust algorithm (if any) that can handle dimensions larger than 2. For instance, considering all possibilities in 3D would be extremely complex.

Could someone provide guidance or an algorithm for this generalized case? I'm implementing this in Python and using NumPy for numerical operations. Any insights or code snippets would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just limit the possible range of the random generated coordinates to the range that the window has.

Comment: Probably it will be easier to check if random point is within the window and regenerate if it is.

Comment: By “no common points” it is meant that the box and the window do not overlap (I changed the question accordingly). Obviously, both LL and UR of the box can be outside the window, but they do overlap.

Comment: @user7647857 You have to check if generated  point for `box` corner is in the window and if is, reject it  and keep generating new until it is outside. Ineffective, but keeps simpler logic.

Comment: @trincot I believe the text is clear: the field and the window are given. The box must be generated.

Comment: Yes, got it now!

Comment: ("The text is clear" but personally I had to re-read the questions three times before I got it. The fact that the title says "generating non-overlapping rectangles", plural, is misleading. Also the fact that the picture shows many rectangles, among which exactly one overlaps others.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach has two steps:

- Generate a random box that is inside the field -- this is trivial
- Verify that the box has no overlap with the window. This consists of the following check *per dimension*:

  - Get the extent of the window in the chosen dimension (you get a low and high coordinate)
  - Get the same for the box in the same dimension.
  - Check whether these two line segments are non-overlapping. If so, we can stop here: the box and the window have no overlap.
- If for none of the dimensions the condition was true, the box and window overlap.

Here is an implementation:

```
from random import randint 

def has_overlap(box1, box2):
    return all(
        high1 >= low2 and high2 >= low1
        for low1, high1, low2, high2 in zip(*box1, *box2)
    )

def generate_box_inside(field):
    return tuple(zip(*(
        sorted([randint(low, high), randint(low, high)])
        for low, high in zip(*field)
    )))

def generate_box(field, window):
    for _ in range(100):  # Make 100 attempts before giving up
        box = generate_box_inside(field)
        if not has_overlap(box, window):
            return box
        print("box", box, "overlaps window", window, "Retrying...")

    print("give up")

# Example run
field = ((0, 0), (100, 100))
window = ((70, 80), (120, 90))
box = generate_box(field, window)
if box:
    print("Found a suitable box", box)
```

You can replace all coordinate-tuples with 3D tuples, and it will work too. The condition is that the first tuple's coordinates are all less than the corresponding member of the second tuple (both for `field` and for `window`).

Comment: I had just fixed this bug before your comment. Please check (`all` instead of `any`).

Comment: I had also done this meanwhile :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how random, or what distribution the 'box' needs to be drawn from. If those don't matter, here is a solution:

For each dimension, select a pair of points for the box (LL and UR), where the coordinates don't overlap the coordinates of the window, and the coordinates are in the field.

```
Consider a window that has coordinates LL(10,30), UR(20, 40)
Consider a field that has coordinates LL(0,0), UR(100,100)

Dimension 0:
choose a pair of points on either of these ranges:
[field.LL[0] -> window.LL[0]] = [0,10]
[window.UR[0] -> field.UR[0]] = [20,100]

For example, [3,7] could be chosen from the first range, 
or [37,88] could be chosen from the second range.

Repeat for each remaining dimension
```

Answer (score 0):

The  `box` that does not overlap with `window` should be within one of the four rectangles made by `field` sides and extensions of `window` sides. We can randomly choose one of rectangles and generate a `box` inside it.

Assuming that `window` is inside `field`, i.e
`wx0 < fx0 < fx1 < wx1 and wy0 < fy0 < wy1 <fy1`

```
from  random import randint

def gbox(f, w):
    (fx0, fy0), (fx1, fy1) = f
    (wx0, wy0), (wx1, wy1) = w

    a = [((fx0, fy0), (wx0, fy1)), ((fx0, fy0), (fx1, wy0)), ((wx1, fy0),(fx1, fy1) ), ((fx0, wy1), (fx1, fy1))]
    r = a[randint(0, 3)]
    (rx0, ry0), (rx1, ry1) = r

    box = ((randint(rx0, rx1), randint(ry0, ry1)), (randint(rx0, rx1), randint(ry0, ry1)))
    return box

f = ((0, 0), (100, 100))
w = ((10, 30), (20, 50))

print('box =', gbox(f, w))
```

Running some tests.

```
box = ((17, 76), (25, 84))
box = ((1, 84), (6, 27))
box = ((28, 19), (35, 30))
```

For 3D case we will have `6` parallelepipeds instead of `4` rectangles.

Comment: If I understand correctly, with field ((0, 0), (5, 5)) and window ((2, 2), (3, 3)), your function cannot generate the box ((0, 0), (2, 5))?

Comment: @Stef Thank you! I made a horrible error. Fixed.